# IBM MQ Internet Pass-Thru licensing requirement

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, xms

We have an IBM MQ Internet Pass-Thru V2.1.0.1(MQIPT) configured within our organization that consumes the messages published by an external organization 'X'. The external organization 'X' has distributed this MQIPT to use within our premises. We are trying to consume the messages published by 'X' to an IBM MQ (fully licensed) hosted on their side via the MQIPT hosted in our premises.

We have used the .NET library 'XMS.Net' (https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/xms-net-%E2%80%93-overview) to consume the messages via MQIPT. The licensing says it is free for a period of 90 days.

In this configuration, what is the licensing requirement that we need for using the XMS.NET IBM C# library?

Can anybody tell me if we need to purchase any licenses in addition to what 'X' already has? If yes, how much does it usually cost?
I am trying to get help from IBM, but considering their prioritization, I hope I can get a quicker answer from here.

Comment: Where do you see this "licensing says it is free for a period of 90 days"?

Comment: This is the Licensing link that I get when I add the IBM® Message Service Client for .NET Standard (XMS .NET)  to my C# project.
https://www14.software.ibm.com/cgi-bin/weblap/lap.pl?amp;li_formnum=L-APIG-C2SEH5

Comment: What software are you downloading that gives you that license?  Sounds like you are downloading the ibm mq eval license.  You can just download the redist client and get the same dlls.  No Eval license required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question covers 2 separate products, MQ Client and MQ IPT.

XMS.Net is part of the MQ Client for .Net, which is a free product:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=information-mq-client-net-license

But MQIPT requires a license. Though I don't think it is licensed on its own, but as part of a full MQ license:
"If you have purchased IBM MQ entitlement, you can install as many copies as required of MQIPT. MQIPT installations are not counted against your purchased IBM MQ entitlement."

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=overview-mq-internet-pass-thru

You will need to ask IBM whether the MQ license of company X covers the MQIPT installations in your network (unlikely), or what is the minimum MQ license you need to purchase to use MQIPT.

Comment: Thank you @Attila Repasi. This was really helpful. 
If I can ask a follow-up question on this, can I use this library for commercial purposes? Do you think I can distribute my software that uses XMS.net library? I want to be clear before going ahead and using this library because the licensing terms could be tricky at places.

Comment: See the redist client download it is just for this purpose.   If you use managed mode you only need to include a few DLLs.